# UIViewAnimation does not work in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewanimation

I try to go back to the first view and animate it. However the animation does not work. The code is shown below:

```
- (IBAction)geriBtnClick:(id)sender {

[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                       forView:self.view cache:YES];

[self.view removeFromSuperview]; //ikinci view kaldır.
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Please advise on what is wrong with this and how it can be resolved.

Comment: What do you expect to happen in the above? You never modify an animatable property. What do you think is going to animate?

Comment: this method is back button' s action. I want to back to root view and with animation. But animation is not work.

Answer (score 1):

The way to manage the back button is with `UINavigationController`. You should be calling `[navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`. That will create the segue you're looking for. Otherwise you're going to have to create the entire transition, just just remove the view. Creating your own transitions is not a beginner subject; you want to use `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I didnt understant you exactly, can you explain how can I change my code?

Comment: Start with the View Controller PG. It explains the various ways to correctly transition between view controllers. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html. The View Controller Catalog is also very helpful to understanding what's available and when to use each: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

every time you are removing the view

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

are you sure about that piece of code like it will remove the current view from the super view and in case if you wana see the view again you should re-add the view once again after the animation for the animation to work.

The code will work one time not again and again